# Pip installing into an older Python version

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install mysql-python using:

```
pip install mysql-python
```

the package is being installed below, although I already have Python 2.6 on the system.

```
/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages
```

How can I get pip to install in:

```
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
```

I tried using:

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/" mysql-python
```

but that didn't work and it outputs:

```
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): mysql-python in 
    /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages
    Cleaning up...
```

Comment: Where is pip and is it a link to a versioned pip e.g. pip-2.5?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should have pip-2.6. If you don't have pip version 2.6 :

You have to install setuptools for Python 2.6 (example : setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg). Then, you have easy_install-2.6. You can do :

```
easy_install-2.6 pip
```

Finally, you have pip version 2.6. To install mysql-python :

```
pip-2.6 install mysql-python
```

Comment: I did `easy_install-2.6 pip` and that ran fine. However, `pip-2.6` fails for me with `ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'pip-2.6') not found`.

Comment: I tried `easy_install-2.6 pip` but got `error: Not a recognized archive type: pip`

Comment: To me, after running easy_install-2.6 pip, the command is "pip2.6", instead of "pip-2.6". The additional hyphen can be tricky.