# Where is BeautifulSoup4 hiding?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip

I did `sudo pip install BeautifulSoup4` and got an awfully optimistic response:

```
Downloading/unpacking beautifulsoup4
  Running setup.py egg_info for package beautifulsoup4
Installing collected packages: beautifulsoup4
  Running setup.py install for beautifulsoup4
Successfully installed beautifulsoup4
Cleaning up..
```

but when I try to use `import BeautifulSoup4` or `from BeautifulSoup4 import BeautifulSoup4` in a script, python says there's no module by that name.

```
> import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup
```

Update: `pip` tells me `beautifulsoup4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages` but I'm running 2.7.2+ (and `print sys.path` sees 2.7 paths) ... so now I need to figure out why `pip` is putting things in the wrong place.

Comment: Run `pip install beautifulsoup4` again to find out where the package has been installed and then in your Python run `import sys` ands `print sys.path` to see where Python looks for modules

Comment: @ColonelPanic  re-running pip tells me `beautifulsoup4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages` but `print sys.path` gives all the paths as `python2.7` ... revising my question.

Comment: You are using a 2.6 pip installation. Install pip for 2.7 (separately) and use `pip-2.7`.

Comment: @ColonelPanic I edited your answer so I could accept it. Feel free to put it back in your own words. Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538329/pip-installing-into-an-older-python-version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663980/importerror-no-module-named-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try `import bs4`. It's unfortunate there's no correspondence between PyPI package name and import name. After that the class names are the same as before eg. `soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(doc)` will work.

If that still doesn't work, try `pip install` again and note the path to the package install. Then in your python console run `import sys` and `print sys.path` to make sure that the path is there.

You might need to explicitly specify `pip-2.7` or switch to `easy_install` (or `easy_install-2.7`)

Comment: That doesn't work either, sadly: `ImportError: No module named bs4`

Comment: @Amanda: Then something else is wrong; the answer is certainly correct, see http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not sure how the BeautifulSoup docs are going to help me troubleshoot `pip`.

Comment: Manually maintained mapping between PyPI package names and import names: https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs/blob/master/pipreqs/mapping

Answer (score 7):

Try this:
`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue while using VS Code and the **Pylance** extension. I was able to resolve it by finding the location of my python packages (in my case it was "c:\python39\lib\site-packages"), and adding that to the external resolution paths in Pylance's settings. Pylance was then able to locate the import. I used below code segment to import BeautifulSoup from bs4.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying the easy_install and pip if things dont work then download the tz package from the package website untar it in a folder. Now open cmd window and go to the directory where you unzip the tz and run the command 'python setup.py install' IT should work