# Having trouble running Beautifulsoup library

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was able to install the library, however, when I try to run it, it shows me the following error.

Don't know what to do, I am going crazy about it. 
Someone please help me!!

[problem when running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAcsP.png)
[installing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZTTX.png)

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: The first issue is a typo, it's `BeautifulSoup` not `BeautifulSoup4`. More importantl, however, is the fact that you're using Conda. This means you shouldn't install the package with pip, see https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/. You shouldn't use the base Conda environment, either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is BeautifulSoup4 hiding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902783/where-is-beautifulsoup4-hiding)

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of adding 4 to the end.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 0):

You're importing from `Beautifulsoup4` what is the wrong package. Instead, `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

For more details, check the PyPi page of the package: https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/