# Installing matplotlib on python version 2.5

Tags: python, matplotlib, psse

I use the power system analysis package pss/e which uses python version 2.5.

I would like to use matplotlib in this environment (I run python from PSS/e not the other way around and have no choice of version). Is it possible? How would install it? I don't think I can install/use PIP in this old version?

I am very new to python! using a 64 bit win7 machine.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know pss/e but all [matplotlib versions prior to 1.2.0](https://matplotlib.org/downloads.html) are available on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/). For Python 2.5 I believe you'll need the **1.1.1** version which you'll be able to find [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.1.1/).

There are [installation instructions](https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#windows) on matplotlib wepage, but if possible the recommended is using PIP, and I quote:

> For standard Python installations, install matplotlib using pip:
>
> ```
> python -m pip install -U pip setuptools
> python -m pip install matplotlib
> ```

The PIP version you should have is (I think) [pip 1.3.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/1.3.1). If you need to perform any of these installations (besides matplotlib) check other questions in SO. It's the best resource since you'll hardly find anyone whose dealings with such an older version are fresh in their mind (I've been using Python for some 7 or 8 years and I don't think I have ever used an older version than 2.7). For example see:

[Pip installing into an older Python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538329/pip-installing-into-an-older-python-version)

[How to setup setuptools for python 2.6 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309412/how-to-setup-setuptools-for-python-2-6-on-windows)